# "Gaining access" to cultural heritage

Tags: word-request

In my university application essay, I would like to indicate that by getting admission into the university, I'll "gain access" to the university's rich cultures and traditions, which are over a hundred years old.

"Gain access" sounds overtly technical than the friendly tone I need. I thought of words like "inherit" but I don't think they fit the case here, because just by getting admitted to the university I'm not going to literally "own" all of their traditions ^_^

What's a good word in this case? Thanks!

Comment: have access to is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Gain access" sounds overtly technical than the friendly tone I need.

I agree.  Really, you *gain access* to people or things.  Cultures are more abstract.

> I thought of words like "inherit" but I don't think they fit the case here, because just by getting admitted to the university I'm not going to literally "own" all of their traditions

I agree as well. *Inherit* means "to receive by being born in" so it doesn't work.

Try these:

> I'll be able to immerse myself in the university's rich cultures and traditions, which are over a hundred years old.
>
> I'll gain exposure to the university's rich cultures and traditions, which are over a hundred years old.